# How to include template code in a package

Tags: meteor

I want a package to expose a template. I managed to get the template to work but I can't add the code for it.

**Here's what works:**

package.js

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Dashboard"
});

Package.on_use(function(api){
    api.use('coffeescript', ['client', 'server']);
    api.use('templating', 'client');

    api.add_files(['dashboard.html'], 'client');
});
```

dashboard.html

```
<template name="dashboard">
  <h1>Hello Dashboard</h1>
</template>
```

I can then use it on my app like so:

```
{{> dashboard}}
```

**Here's what doesn't work**

package.js

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Dashboard"
});

Package.on_use(function(api){
    api.use('coffeescript', ['client', 'server']);
    api.use('templating', 'client');

    api.add_files(['dashboard.html', 'dashboard.coffee'], 'client');
});
```

dashboard.html

```
<template name="dashboard">
  <h1>Hello Dashboard</h1>
  {{name}}
</template>
```

dashboard.coffee

```
Template.dashboard.helpers
  name: -> "John Doe"
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

Comment: Just put the coffeescript in a `Meteor.startup` block, and it should work fine.

Comment: @richsilv It works but how come I haven't seen any package in atmosphere use Meteor.startup for the template code? They all just use Template.blah.helpers directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add handlebars in the use list api.use(['templating', 'handlebars'], 'client');

Comment: What about `api.use(['templating', 'spacebars', 'ui'], 'client')`?

Comment: Same error when I don't wrap the code in a Meteor.startup block like richsilv mentioned. No clue why.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the source code of popular packages which use coffeescript and templates, as in your case - like `accounts-entry`

Here is its `package.js`:

https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/blob/master/package.js

So, the most important is:

```
  api.use([
    'templating',
    'handlebars',
    'coffeescript']
  , 'client');
```

Comment: Same error when I don't wrap the code in a Meteor.startup block like richsilv mentioned. No clue why.